# how to ignore missing statemet in jenkins test coverage in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, jenkins, pylint

Is it possible to ignore the missing branch coverage? I am using jenkins for test coverage and pylint testing. Is there any possibility to ingore missing statements and get 100% branch coverage? Maybe a property that can be set in project setting?

Comment: If there are statements that aren't covered, why should you see 100% coverage?

Comment: actually i want to ignore the missing line in generated test report. so that i can get ~ 100 % coverage.  
**missing occurs in if-else block.**

Comment: But you don't have 100% coverage. Because you're not covering that line. So write a test to cover that line (or accept <100% test coverage, which is also fine).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of my question.
1) create .coveragerc file in your django project
2) define

```
JENKINS_TASKS = ('django_jenkins.tasks.run_pylint',)
COVERAGE_EXCLUDES_FOLDERS = ['packsit/migrations/*','packsit/api/v1/images.py']
COVERAGE_RCFILE = '.coveragerc'
```

in your setting file.
3) .coveragerc file should contains:

```
[run]
branch = True

omit =
    */.local/*
    /usr/*
[report]

exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    def __repr__
    if self\.debug
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError
    if 0:
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
    return
    try:
    except:
    if
    self.*


ignore_errors = True
include = 
    packsit/api/v1/client/*
[html]
directory = coverage_html_report
```

then run command on terminal:

```
$ python manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage --coverage-format html --coverage-exclude=COVERAGE_EXCLUDES_FOLDERS
```

this will exclude 'if, return, self, try , except' from report generated.